# Azure Data Factory Copy activity not applying compression for avro

Tags: copy, compression, azure-pipelines, avro, azure-data-factory

I am applying "avroCompressionCodec": "snappy" for avro dataset. However Copy activity in Azure Data Factory V2 pipeline ignores compression. At design time it shows a warning - The compression type will be ignored when using Avro dataset as copy destination.

Do we know how to apply compression in this case?

Answer (score 0):

As it is stated in the [official documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs#compression-support). Compression settings are not currently supported for AvroFormat data.

> Compression settings are not supported for data in the AvroFormat, OrcFormat, or ParquetFormat. When reading files in these formats, Data Factory detects and uses the compression codec in the metadata. When writing to files in these formats, Data Factory chooses the default compression codec for that format. For example, ZLIB for OrcFormat and SNAPPY for ParquetFormat.

You can post your idea to Microsoft [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory), asking for the feature to support compression settings for AvroFormat data.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you further clarify what is the default compression codec used by Data Factory for Avro format (answer mentions defaults for orc and parquet)? Also, is there any chance of support for compression settings coming soon? Sample json in official documents mentions using of "avroCompressionCodec":.

Comment: The [default compressioncodec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-avro#dataset-properties) for Avro is 'none'. You can  [enter your idea](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory) to Microsoft Azure Data Factory team, to submit your requests to support avro compression type. The azure data factory dev team hopefully will review this request and fix it soon.

Comment: Thanks, have published at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/39173467-support-avro-compression-type-in-azure-data-factor.